# signInWithRedirect is not working in safari

Tags: next.js, firebase-authentication, safari

I deployed a Next.js webpage in AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment.
I implemented the social login feature through Firebase auth.
The methods used are `signInWithRedirect` and `onAuthStateChanged`.
In the local environment, all browsers work fine, but when I used the Safari browser in  production, Google and Apple login does not work.
In the Firebase docs, I found 5 suggestions for browsers that block third party storage.
Among them, I tested the reverse proxy method, but it still doesn't work on the safari browser.
(I use docker and nginx).

1. edit nginx.conf
2. add rewrites to next.config.js

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Running into the same issue.

Comment: @plat_winz I fixed the issue by changing my deployment from `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` to `Firebase Hosting`.
I was unable to resolve it within the `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` environment.